# loading a custom stylesheet in a function

Tags: css

im having problems loading my custom stylesheet inside `wp-admin`

here is my code to load stylesheet inside my theme's `function.php`

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_style');

function my_custom_style() 
{
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css />';  
}
```

and some functions that adds `<div>` on my `admin-header` and `admin-footer`

```
add_action('admin_head', 'echo_html');
function echo_html(){
    echo '<div class="superwrap"> test superwrap';

}

add_action('wp_footer', 'echo_foo');
function echo_foo(){
    echo '</div>';

}
```

when i echo below `code` inside my `my_custom_style` function, it works. but when i link the stylesheet, it doesnt load.

```
 <style>
.superwrap {
    padding:20px 10px 10px 5px;
    background:green;
    min-height:100%;
    } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include custom styles and scripts, you should be using [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) like so:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', my_enqueue_admin_styles);
function my_enqueue_admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-style', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/style.css', array(), 'screen');
}
```

You want to use this method, as it will add your CSS after the default and thus it will allow you to overwrite the WP styles.

Then, look at the source of any admin page, and search for your CSS. Make sure the URL there is accurate. If it is, the style will load.